# how to pass array in helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

I have helmfile

```
releases:
  - name: controller
    values:    
      - values/valuedata.yaml
    hooks:
      {{ toYaml .Values.hooks }}
```

file with values

```
hooks:
  - events: [ "presync" ]
    showlogs: true
    command: "bash"
    args: [ "args"]
```

I want to pass the hooks from values how I can do it ?
I tried many ways and I got an error
This is the command

```
helmfile --file ./myhelmfile.yaml sync
```

```
 failed to read myhelmfile.yaml: reading document at index 1: yaml: line 26: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is to inline part of the `values.yaml` into your template. Therefore you need to take care of the indentation properly.

In your case I think it'll be something like this:

```yaml
releases:
  - name: controller
    values:    
      - values/valuedata.yaml
    hooks:
{{ toYaml .Values.hooks | indent 6 }}
```

You can find a working example of a similar case [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/3dc89b407d61896cfac2be029223f5fb8bd6e65d/stable/hazelcast/templates/statefulset.yaml#L28).

Comment: Why the indent is 6 ?

Comment: I think it's 6, but you can check if it's correct. I think 6, because you'd like to have 6 speca characters in the line after `hooks:`